# ExpandBar/ExpandItem background/foreground colors in Java SWT

Tags: java, colors, background, swt, foreground

I'm looking to manage colors of headers of my expandItem in SWT, and I'm not able to change the background or the foreground (swt gtk 32bit) or only background (swt win 64).

Is there some particular way to do that?
I'm already setting:

```
exp_bar.setBackground(new Color(display, GUISetting.MAIN_BACKGROUND));
exp_bar.setForeground(new Color(display, GUISetting.MAIN_TEXT_COLOR));
```

But this does not seem to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWT, these widgets are supplied by OS. if you look at documentation setBackground(), it says the parameters are just hints. they might be honored or not, it all depends on OS.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65497.html) page, this behaviour is intended. The widgets are supplied by the OS. The OS uses a texture and SWT decided, that you cannot set the color on a widget with a texture.

There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=131265) that you can support.

However, these posts are quite old (2006). Maybe it was fixed till now, but I couldn't find anything...